# "Unable to find local grunt" after every hudson build

Tags: jenkins, gruntjs, hudson

Hudson unable to locate local `grunt` after every build.

The only workaround solution i found is installing local `grunt`, local grunt plugins as part of every `hudson` build.

workaround solution: `cd src/main && npm install grunt --save-dev && npm install && grunt`

expected solution: `cd src/main && grunt(close to)`